# Is there a way to set chrome zoom 200% for any web page?

Tags: google-chrome

Right clicking the 3 vertical dots (Kebab) button at the top right hand corner, would launch this menu

[image]

Clicking the menu command "Zoom" pointed out by the red arrow, would zoom current web page.

When I open a new URL, I have to do the zoom for the new page.

Is there a default setting that zooming a specific, such as 200%, for any web page?

I don't want to change the display options for whole operating system, since I need to use normal size on other apps.

Actually, I want the default 200% zoom applies only for one logged chrome.

For example, I have 2 logged chrome, userA and userB, I want the default 200% zoom applies only for userA and leave the chrome where userB singed in alone.

Please give a specific setting path, from which menu command to submenu command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to chrome://settings/appearance and set **Page zoom**.